# Mercurial: Renaming a file results in duplicate contents in repository?

Tags: mercurial

I just start using Mercurial yesterday (I don't have much programming experiences). I noticed, if I rename a 200MB file, ideally the repository size should not change, but I found it increased 200MB.

Is this a bug/weakness of Mercurial? Any chance it could be fixed/improved in future?

---

**Update:**

I have just tried TortoiseGit 64bit version on Windows 7 64bit. It didn't create duplicate contents when renaming files. But it seems once I renamed a file, its history was lost.

---

**Update 2:**

See [tonfa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/148532/tonfa)'s comment below. From Mercurial wiki - [GSoC Ideas 2010](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/SummerOfCode/Ideas2010):

> ### Project Ideas
>
> #### Lightweight copies/renames
>
> (very difficult - a successful student
> will become an expert in Mercurial's
> storage format and transmission
> protocol)
>
> Copies and renames currently are not
> too efficient. Mercurial copies the
> copied/renamed source file to the new
> initial revision of the target file in
> its internal history store. For
> renames, this is especially
> counter-intuitive, as renaming a large
> file grows the store by the file's
> size. It would be better if Mercurial
> had some way of referring to the
> existing revision from the new file,
> while preserving backwards
> compatbility and bounded I/O
> guarantees for retrieving revisions.
> See [issue883](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/bts/issue883) for discussion.
> There's an mq from an old attempt at
> this located [here](http://bitbucket.org/Murkt/hg-lwcopy-mq/).
>
> Contact: mpm, tonfa, cyanite

Comment: This is being worked on, search lwcopy in the Mercurial wiki and mailing list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it is not a bug. Renaming in mercurial causes removing file in old place and creating it in new one (with keeping the reference though, for merge and logging purposes).

So at least for now you can do nothing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So each time I rename a file or folder, duplicate contents are created in the repository. This is a bad news for me, as I'm the kind of person that enjoy renaming my resource files. I will give Git a try.

Comment: @caveman: if you rename sources - it is not a big issue, but if you keep there 200MB binary files... :-S

Comment: caveman: just rename with Mercurial and ignore the space hit for now -- when light-weight copies are implemented, then new clones will be small again.

Comment: @Martin Geisler: That's a wonderful news! The only reason I switch from Mercurial to Git is the rename issue. Now I'm switching back to Mercurial :)

Comment: @Martin Geisler: When light-weight copies are implemented, will two files with same content (same hash value different names) store only once in repository (just like Git)?

Comment: @caveman: no, this feature isn't planned (it would break other optimizations to minimize disk access)